# PHP Get value from drop down option (int) type

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm having problem with capturing the value from drop down list. This is my code for drop down list which is product id.

```
<select name="id" id="id" ONCHANGE="location =this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" >
<option value="---">---</option>
<?php
    foreach( $products as $ID => $info ){
    echo '<option value="new_purchase.php?id=' . $ID . '"';
    echo isset( $id ) && $id == $ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '>' . $info['id'] . '</option>'; }                                                         
                        ?>
</select>
```

And this is my code for capture the value.

```
 $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string ($_POST['$("#id:selected").val()'] );
```

The query run but it stores 0 as product id value no matter what I chose.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mashing up PHP and JavaScript. You just need the name of the form field in your `$_POST` array:

```
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['$("#id:selected").val()']);
```

should be:

```
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
```

**UPDATE**

and change

```
echo '<option value="new_purchase.php?id=' . $ID . '"';
```

to

```
echo '<option value="' . $ID . '"';
```

**UPDATE Part Deaux**

and change

```
ONCHANGE="location =this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"
```

to

```
ONCHANGE="location = 'new_purchase.php?id=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"
```

Comment: What do you see when you do a `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: It shows  ["id"]=> string(21) "new_purchase.php?id=6". I think this is the problem some how it gets the whole address not the number

Comment: And what sence does it have: onchange => `location.href = 5`?

Comment: It doesn't but it doesn't seem to be affecting the sending or receiving of the form data based on the var_dump the provided..

Comment: I tried the update one. It gives me 404 page error because when you pick an product id. It will automatically fill out the page with product information associate with that id.

Comment: @user1754822 So once again. 1). You select the value. 2). `onchange` redirects browser to new location `abc.com/new_purchase.php?id=6`. 3). Inside of `new_purchase.php` you should be able to read GET parameter `id`. If you can't, this is strange.

Comment: Now I see what you meant. I've updated my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not submitting a form and just changing a `window.location` your POST array will be empty. Instead you should read GET parameter, not POST:

```
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<select name="id" id="id" ONCHANGE="location ='http://site.com/new_purchase.php?id='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" >
<option value="---">---</option>
<?php
   foreach( $products as $ID => $info ){
     echo '<option value="'.$ID .'"';
     echo isset( $id ) && $id == $ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
     echo '>' . $info['id'] . '</option>'; }                                                         
                    ?>
</select>
```

i guess your database is expecting integer for the column of product id, right? so it is a mismatch of data type.

Comment: As i commented above. When you pick an product id the address will change to abc.com/new_purchase.php?id=6 and refresh the page to fill out the information associated with id. If I use your code, it give me the address abc.com/6 which is 404 error.

Comment: change this thing : `location =this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;` to `location ='abc.com/new_purchase.php?id='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;`